# How can I import users into WordPress?

Tags: cms, users, bulk-import

I have a spreadsheet (XLS) of names, email addresses, and passwords from another content management system. Is there a way to import these folks as users (I think subscriber level, but some may be Editors as well) into WordPress?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A new file, `import.php`:

```
<?php

define('WP_INSTALLING', true); // this is required. i forget why!

include '/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php';
include ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php'; // wp_insert_user()

$userdata = array('user_login' => 'jdoe', 'user_pass' => 'foobar');
$user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
```

Check `wp_insert_user()` for other possible fields. Run `update_usermeta()` for any additional needed meta fields. (Including user level, though there may be convenience functions.)

Note that here at work we redefine the `wp_authenticate()` function (it's in `pluggable.php`, so it can be replaced by defining it in your own plugin) and creating user accounts on-demand if they don't exist at login time.

Comment: I had not heard of `wp_insert_user()` - nice!

Comment: Double-nice because you can use it on existing users (just pass `$userdata['ID']`). I recommend being familiar with both `wp_insert_user()` and `wp_update_user()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a plugin for that. When done, remove the plugin.

[This one by Dagon Design](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/import-users-plugin-for-wordpress/) seems to do the trick, but it was not updated for wordpress 3. Don't know if it will work, so you migth want to try it on a sample wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly import them using the SQL databases, running an SQL query using the code from the downloaded SQL file from the previous server which contains all the users. That's what I would do, it is very easy.

Comment: Using a SQL query, you wouldn't be able to import the passwords. WordPress doesn't use the MySQL PASSWORD() function, it uses [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Comment: @PHPass I never said import them using an sql query. There is no such thing. You import them from another SQL file in the import screen. Your comment is irrelevant and should be ignored. Maybe you commented on the wrong answer?

Comment: Your answer seemed like you were suggesting that OP turn his XLS into SQL statements, or import (e.g. as CSV using phpmyadmin or similar) directly into the database. That's a great suggestion, but OP wouldn't be able to import the passwords as-is, which is what I was noting, and for which my comment is relevant. If you're instead suggesting (as it sounds from your comment) that OP import from his old non-WP database to his WP database, that *would not* work. In that case, my comment is not relevant, but neither is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily migrate users using the free plugin [Import export WordPress users](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/)